# Why I am getting no output?

Tags: c

I have written this code to convert a string into float number (IMPLEMENTED MY OWN ATOF() function in c)

the output should be this:

```
Enter A number: 
6
your number is : 6.00
```

CORRECTED:
but I get this.

```
 Enter A number: 
    6
Press enter to continue:
```

I am getting this output:

```
 Enter A number: 
        6
your number is: 0.00
Press enter to continue:
```

The following is the code that I wrote. I feel like I have missed something with the pointer or might have made mistake in the calculation. But as for as I see, everything seems good for me but why it is giving me 0.00?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 250

float myAtof(char *string, char *error);

int main()
{
    char string[SIZE];            // Array declaration.
    float fnum1;
    char errorState=0;

    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    gets(string);

     fnum1=myAtof(string,&errorState);
   
   if (errorState==0){
        printf("Your number is: %.2f \n", fnum1);
    }
    else if (errorState==1){
        printf("Error has been occurred due to inappropriate input!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

float myAtof(char* string, char* error){          // Function to convert string into float.

     *error != '1';

     float num=  0;
     float decimalFlag = 1;
     int decimalNumberFound = 0;



    for(int i = 0; i< strlen(string); i++){
        char ch = string[i];
       


if(ch != '.' && (ch < '0' || ch >'9'))
        {
            *error ='1';
            return 0;
            }
        if( decimalNumberFound == 1 && ch == '.')
        {
            *error = '1';
            return 0;

            }
        if(ch = '.')
        {
            decimalNumberFound = 1;

            }

        else {
            num = num * 10 + (ch - '0');

            if(decimalNumberFound ==1)

                decimalFlag = decimalFlag * 10;

            }
    }

        num = num / decimalFlag;

        return num;

}
```

Comment: Hint: `1 != '1'`

Comment: Tip: `x = x * y` is `x *= y`, and so on.

Comment: Using ASCII characters for errors is not only bizarre, it's wrong as `'0'` is not false.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. but I get output as 0.00 for all inputs? any tip? any guidance? is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I will not tell you where the error is, but remember **never** to code "this will not happen". Here, you do:

```
if (errorState==0) {
    printf("Your number is: %.2f \n", fnum1);
} else if (errorState==1) {
    printf("Error has been occurred due to inappropriate input!\n");
}
```

You just said, "*it will never happen* that errorState is neither 0 nor 1".

Try rather:

```
if (errorState==0) {
    printf("Your number is: %.2f \n", fnum1);
} else if (errorState==1) {
    printf("Error has been occurred due to inappropriate input!\n");
} else {
    printf("Rats! errorCode is %d! This cannot be happening!\n", (int)errorCode);
}
```

so that *whatever happens*, you *should* get some input.

Comment: Extra `"` in that rats line.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this method in my future works.

Comment: @LSerni  Any tip or guidance, why I am getting output as 0.00 for all inputs ( integer inputs).